# The Chain Rule for Differetial of a Map

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, manifolds, differential-topology

I am reading "An introduction to manifolds" by Loring Tu. And there in the proof of the chain rule for differential of a map i couldn't understand the last step. The following is the step that i am unable to understand:
$$(G_*(F_*X_p))f=(F_*X_p)(f\circ G)$$
I am attaching the screen shot of proof where this  is given and i have highlighted the step which i can't understand. Also note that they've defined the differential of a map in the previous section of which i am also attaching the screenshot.The only step that i can't understand is that is highlighted(in the screenshot) and written above.[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $(G_*(Y_q))f=Y_q(f\circ G)$.
Now take $Y_q=F_*(X_p)$

Comment: Yes i think that is correct since $Y_q=F_* (X_p)$ will live inside the tangent vector space at point F(p) of manifold M .